# $.load() links do not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm loading a page into another page. It has GET variables in the page URL. For some reason, when I load it onto another page, it loads fine, but the links don't work. When I load it by itself, the links work. The links are another jQuery `.click()` function with a `.load()` function called in it.

Here's the first load function. This one works fine:

```
$(".menuDay").click(function () {
   $("body").append('<div id="ScheduleInfo"></div>');
   $("#ScheduleInfo").load('Utilities/AppointmentScheduling.php?Year=' + year + '&Month=' + month + '&Day=' + day);
});
```

Here's the second load function. This one works when the page is opened up directly, but not when it is opened up through the implementation of jQuery's `.load()` listed above:

```
$("table.HourlySchedule tr").click(function () {
   $("body").append('<div class="AddAppointment"></div>');
   $("div.AddAppointment").load('AddAppointment.php?Year=' + Year +'&Month=' KK+ Month + '&Day=' + Day);
});
```

Comment: For clarification, the second snippet appears in AppointmentScheduling.php?

Answer (score 0):

Why not do something like;

```
function storeIt(data) {
   $("#ScheduleInfo").empty().html(data);
}
$.get('Utilities/AppointmentScheduling.php?Year=' + year + '&Month=' + month + '&Day=' + day, storeIt);
```

*(jQuery lib is needed)*

Comment: Would that be the same as `$.get('Utilities/AppointmentScheduling.php?Year=' + year + '&Month=' + month + '&Day=' + day, function (data) {$("#ScheduleInfo").html(data);});`? Because I just tried that and it did the same thing.

Comment: It would be the same, yes.

Comment: I just changed it on the other page too, to that format, and it didn't change anything..

Comment: "didn't change anything" meaning it's still not working? Debug the code by logging the console. Would you mind pastebin'ing the source that isn't working?

Comment: That's pretty much the code that's not working. It would be a bit of work to send all of the code, as there's a fair amount of code on the page. Still, that's exactly what's not working. The console doesn't say anything I think would be relevant. There's a couple weird errors in the jQuery file itself, but I don't know why. I think that code just doesn't work...

Comment: I used the code I supplied on a project of mine, and it worked - which is strange, as it's not working correctly for you.

Comment: That is very strange. I'll look into it. Here's the code if you wanted to look into it: http://we.tl/q8JkE6LyoC The problem is rather apparent, on the index page, where you click on a green square, another page pops up, then the .click stops working.